# Inserting values from Table Valued Parameter into a database table

Tags: sql-server-2008, table-valued-parameters

How would I insert values from a table valued parameter into a table

as it is right now it doesnt work.

Which is the best way of doing this?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SaveDomainObject]
@Fields dbo.TemplateFieldsAsSqlParameter READONLY

AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO DomainObjectFields
    VALUES (@UniqueKeyDomainObjectField, @Fields.FieldName, @Fields.FieldValue,@DateCreated, @DateUpdated, @Fields.AllowDuplicates)     

 END
```

the compiler tells me I need to daclere the Scalar variable @Fields.

How would I dothis?

kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should think of the table value parameter as a table, so you simply insert into your table by SELECTING from the table value parameter.
If you have other fields that aren't in the TVP, just add them into the SELECT as you would normally.

```
INSERT INTO DomainObjectFields(column list)
SELECT (column list) 
FROM TableFieldsAsSQLParameter
```

Comment: How come you do not use the @Fields in the FROM as opposed to the TableFieldsAsSQLParameter?